# Barcode scanner disabled when closing app

Tags: pos-for-.net

I'm using a barcode scanner (LS2208 OPOS mode) in an application and every time I close it the scanner is disabled. It starts to work again when I reopen the app.

In my app there is no call to disabled it, so why is this happening? Is this normal ?

The same thing happens with the sample app in the POS for .NET SDK

Answer (score 0):

That is normal behavior.
Calls such as Close or Release method(Release is exclusive device only), or application termination or abort, will disable the OPOS/POS for.NET device.

However, termination or abort of the application may not be disable depending on timing.
It is considered a bug in either OPOS/POS for.NET/application.